# How to deal with overlapping text with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in Pygame. One of the biggest issues I've been having is trying to get text to change. right now I am trying to get the show_score() function to properly update it's value without affecting the background. Issues I've ran into is that the text will overlap or the text will not overlap but the background will fill everything.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import sys

#Global variables
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
#font = None
def main():
    board = [["", "", ""], ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]]

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clicker =""
    # Setting up Screen

    pygame.display.set_caption('TicTacToe')

    # Game Buttons
    x_button = pygame.Rect((screen_width / 2)+200 , (screen_height / 2) +150, 30, 30)
    o_button = pygame.Rect((screen_width / 2) + 250, (screen_height / 2) + 150, 30, 30)
    s_button = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +200, (75),100,50)

    # Board Buttons
    one_one = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -125, 0, 100, (500/3))
    one_two = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -25, 0, 100, (500/3))
    one_three = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +75, 0, 100, (500/3))
    two_one = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -125, 500/3, 100, (500/3))
    two_two = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -25,  500/3,100, (500/3))
    two_three = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +75, 500/3,100, (500/3))
    three_one = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -125, (500/3)*2, 100, (500/3))
    three_two = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -25,   (500/3)*2,100, (500/3))
    three_three = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +75,  (500/3)*2,100, (500/3))

    bg_color = pygame.Color('grey12')
    light_grey = (200, 200, 200)
    light_grey2= (224, 236, 255)
    green = (40, 189, 52)

    # Set up
    screen.fill(bg_color)

    #Start Button


    #Board Buttons
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, x_button)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, o_button)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, one_one)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, one_two)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, one_three)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, two_one)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, two_two)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, two_three)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, three_one)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, three_two)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, three_three)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, s_button)
    #Horizontal Lines
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) +175,0),((screen_width/2)+175,screen_height))
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) +75,0),((screen_width/2)+75,screen_height))
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -25,0),((screen_width/2)-25,screen_height))
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -125,0),((screen_width/2)-125,screen_height))

    #Vertical Lines
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -125,(screen_height/3)),((screen_width/2)+175,(screen_height/3)))
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -125,(screen_height/3)*2 ),((screen_width/2)+175,(screen_height/3)*2))

    #Text for game


    #x_str = 'X'
    #img = font.render(x_str, True, (214, 55, 47))
    img2 = font.render('O', True, (214, 55, 47))
    img3 = font.render('Start', True, (214, 55, 47))
    img4 = font.render('Stop', True, (214, 55, 47))
    #screen.blit(img,((screen_width / 2)+210 , (screen_height / 2) +160))
    screen.blit(img2, ((screen_width / 2) + 260, (screen_height / 2) + 160))

    txt = 0
    #show_score(txt)
    while True:
        #pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = event.pos  # gets mouse position
                if x_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    clicker ="x"
                    txt +=1
                    screen.fill(bg_color)
                    show_score(txt)
                    print('button was pressed at {0}'.format(mouse_pos))
                elif o_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    clicker = "o"


        #Updates window
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

    # print(checkwon(board))

def show_score(x_str):
    img = font.render(str(x_str), True, (214, 55, 47))
    screen.blit(img,((screen_width / 2)+210 , (screen_height / 2) +160))




def checkDuplicates(listOfElems):
    setOfElems = set()
    for elem in listOfElems:
        if elem in setOfElems:
            return True
        else:
            setOfElems.add(elem)
    return False


def checkwon(board):
    if is_row_win(board) == 0 and is_col_win(board) == 0 and is_diagonal_win(board) == 0:
        return "Is a draw"
    elif is_row_win(board) != 0:
        return is_row_win(board)
    elif is_col_win(board) != 0:
        return is_row_win(board)
    elif is_diagonal_win(board) != 0:
        return is_diagonal_win(board)


def is_row_win(board):
    lst = []
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board)):
            lst.append(board[row][col])
        if lst[0] == lst[1] and lst[1] == lst[2]:
            return lst[0]
        lst = []
    return 0


def is_col_win(board):
    if board[1][0] == board[2][0] and board[2][0] == board[0][0]:
        return board[0][1]
    elif board[1][1] == board[2][1] and board[2][1] == board[0][1]:
        return board[0][1]
    elif board[1][2] == board[0][2] and board[0][2] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][1]
    return 0


def is_diagonal_win(board):
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][0]
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] and board[2][0] == board[1][1]:
        return board[0][0]
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to (re)draw the complete scene in the application loop in each frame.

```py
import pygame
import sys

#Global variables
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
#font = None
def main():
    board = [["", "", ""], ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]]

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clicker =""
    # Setting up Screen

    pygame.display.set_caption('TicTacToe')

    # Game Buttons
    x_button = pygame.Rect((screen_width / 2)+200 , (screen_height / 2) +150, 30, 30)
    o_button = pygame.Rect((screen_width / 2) + 250, (screen_height / 2) + 150, 30, 30)
    s_button = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +200, (75),100,50)

    # Board Buttons
    one_one = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -125, 0, 100, (500/3))
    one_two = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -25, 0, 100, (500/3))
    one_three = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +75, 0, 100, (500/3))
    two_one = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -125, 500/3, 100, (500/3))
    two_two = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -25,  500/3,100, (500/3))
    two_three = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +75, 500/3,100, (500/3))
    three_one = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -125, (500/3)*2, 100, (500/3))
    three_two = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) -25,   (500/3)*2,100, (500/3))
    three_three = pygame.Rect((screen_width/2) +75,  (500/3)*2,100, (500/3))

    bg_color = pygame.Color('grey12')
    light_grey = (200, 200, 200)
    light_grey2= (224, 236, 255)
    green = (40, 189, 52)


    #x_str = 'X'
    #img = font.render(x_str, True, (214, 55, 47))
    img2 = font.render('O', True, (214, 55, 47))
    img3 = font.render('Start', True, (214, 55, 47))
    img4 = font.render('Stop', True, (214, 55, 47))
    #screen.blit(img,((screen_width / 2)+210 , (screen_height / 2) +160))

    txt = 0
    #show_score(txt)
    while True:
        #pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = event.pos  # gets mouse position
                if x_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    clicker ="x"
                    txt +=1
                    print('button was pressed at {0}'.format(mouse_pos))
                elif o_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    clicker = "o"

        # Set up
        screen.fill(bg_color)

        #Board Buttons
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, x_button)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, o_button)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, one_one)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, one_two)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, one_three)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, two_one)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, two_two)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, two_three)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, three_one)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, three_two)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, three_three)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, s_button)
        #Horizontal Lines
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) +175,0),((screen_width/2)+175,screen_height))
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) +75,0),((screen_width/2)+75,screen_height))
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -25,0),((screen_width/2)-25,screen_height))
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -125,0),((screen_width/2)-125,screen_height))

        #Vertical Lines
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -125,(screen_height/3)),((screen_width/2)+175,(screen_height/3)))
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,light_grey2, ((screen_width/2) -125,(screen_height/3)*2 ),((screen_width/2)+175,(screen_height/3)*2))

        screen.blit(img2, ((screen_width / 2) + 260, (screen_height / 2) + 160))
        show_score(txt)

        #Updates window
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

    # print(checkwon(board))

def show_score(x_str):
    img = font.render(str(x_str), True, (214, 55, 47))
    screen.blit(img,((screen_width / 2)+210 , (screen_height / 2) +160))




def checkDuplicates(listOfElems):
    setOfElems = set()
    for elem in listOfElems:
        if elem in setOfElems:
            return True
        else:
            setOfElems.add(elem)
    return False


def checkwon(board):
    if is_row_win(board) == 0 and is_col_win(board) == 0 and is_diagonal_win(board) == 0:
        return "Is a draw"
    elif is_row_win(board) != 0:
        return is_row_win(board)
    elif is_col_win(board) != 0:
        return is_row_win(board)
    elif is_diagonal_win(board) != 0:
        return is_diagonal_win(board)


def is_row_win(board):
    lst = []
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board)):
            lst.append(board[row][col])
        if lst[0] == lst[1] and lst[1] == lst[2]:
            return lst[0]
        lst = []
    return 0


def is_col_win(board):
    if board[1][0] == board[2][0] and board[2][0] == board[0][0]:
        return board[0][1]
    elif board[1][1] == board[2][1] and board[2][1] == board[0][1]:
        return board[0][1]
    elif board[1][2] == board[0][2] and board[0][2] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][1]
    return 0


def is_diagonal_win(board):
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][0]
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] and board[2][0] == board[1][1]:
        return board[0][0]
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)